# SAS convert string to number with input function

Tags: string, input, sas, numeric

how can i convert a string with only numbers to numeric,  i have this:

```
mydataset:

StringNumber
25 
270
```

the length is $3

when i use this code, removing blanks.

```
data eg1;
set   myDataSet;
number=input(strip(StrinNumber),8.);
run;
```

in the result
the first obs is missing, and the second is 270 (ok).

i tried:

```
number=input(combpl(StrinNumber),8.);
number=input(compress(StrinNumber),8.);
```

and the result is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular reason your code shouldn't have worked, but in any event this is simpler:

```
data test;
length stringNumber $3;
input StringNumber $;
datalines;
25 
270
;;;;
run;

data want;
set test;
number = input(stringNumber,3.);
put number=;
run;
```

The 3. is the length of the string, and you don't need to strip blanks off.

If this doesn't work, I would guess your 25 is not truly the number 25 plus a space, but instead has some non-space character (including NBSP, `'A0'x`, which is common on data grabbed from the web).

You can try:

```
data want;
set test;
number = input(compress(stringNumber,,'kd'),3.);
put number=;
run;
```

which will remove all non-digit characters from the string.  If you're confident in your string having only numbers and spaces-of-some-form, then this should be safe; if it might contain other characters which might validly indicate a record you don't want (including things like "1.3" where this will return "13"), this could be risky without more detailed coding.

Comment: thanks, the first  "number = input(stringNumber,3.);" doesn't work. i had to use compress, thanks again.